# Which ROS for Ubuntu 23.10 on RPI5

Tags: ros, ubuntu, raspberrypi

I got my hands on a RPi5, only to discover that at least Ubuntu 23.10 is required because of the new chipset.

How would I go about installing a ROS version on Ubuntu 23.10. Would I have to build from source, or can I get away by using Iron or Humble?

The Ubuntu 23.10 is integrated with lxd, so as last resort ROS can be run with LXD or Docker, but that adds an unwanted latency.

Any ideas / recommendations / help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the current [ros2 binary releases](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/releases) are for ubuntu 22. So yes, you'll have to build from source (or use a docker image.)